# Cut/Copy/Paste in Quicktime X

Tags: macos, quicktime

In Quicktime 7 it was super easy to make a selection with in/out points and cut/copy/paste that video.  How do you achieve that functionality in Quicktime X?

I see Trim mode - that's only a small subset of what was possible in 7.  How can you delete a span of video from the middle of a clip, or paste that to another part of a clip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickTime **Player** X does not have many of the more useful editing features that was available in QuickTime Player 7. You can find QuickTime Player 7 in your Utilities folder if it was installed when you upgraded to Snow Leopard.

Of note, QuickTime X is a new beast that contains QuickTime 7. The Players are completely separate entities from (but use) the QuickTime framework.

Comment: If you didn't have QT Pro (ie the paid version) when you upgraded to Snow Leopard you can still install it: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3678

Answer (score 1):

Quicktime X is not as capable as Quicktime 7 yet.  The QT Cocoa API that it uses is not yet feature-complete.  Thus, the older Carbon-based Quicktime 7 is still needed to perform some kinds of edits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Edit > Split Clip` <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to cut a video at the playhead.

You can use this as an alternative to `Trim`. Use Split Clip then delete either the left or right clip. It's much easier to choose a specific frame using Split Clip keyboard controls rather than draggable Trim controls.

> How can you delete a span of video from the middle of a clip

Split the clip twice. Then delete the middle segment you've created.

> or paste that to another part of a clip?

Use `Edit > Insert Clip After Selection...` to insert a new clip.

After you have used `Split Clip`, select one of the resulting clips. It will be highlighted in Yellow. You can drag to rearrange the clips, or press <kbd>delete</kbd> to cut the clip out of the video.

[image: Split Clip]